# How to replace ado.net and SQLwith EF and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ado.net

I have an old code written in ado.net with sql, i thought of to change with EF and linq ,here table i am using is `GP_REGION` and i want to complete the line  `var test = db3.GP_REGION.Where(aa=>aa.??????????);`  Can anybody replace the old ado.net code

Here is the full code

```
    GPentities db1 = new GPentities();

    var test = db3.GP_REGION.Where(aa=>aa.??????????);

 //this is the line which i want to complete
```

Following is the existing SQL code

```
SELECT distinct GP_REGION.REGION_MAIN Region_Code,
            R1.REGION_NAME FROM GP_REGION INNER JOIN GP_REGION R1 
            ON GP_REGION.REGION_MAIN = R1.REGION_CODE WHERE GP_REGION.REGION_HAS_DATA='Y'
            AND GP_REGION.REGION_MAIN IN (SELECT DISTINCT AR.BRANCH_CODE FROM PORTAL.UA_APPLN_ROLE AR 
            INNER JOIN PORTAL.UA_GROUP G ON AR.GROUP_CODE = G.GROUP_CODE
            WHERE G.USER_ID = '" + Global.UserId() + "' AND AR.APPLICATION_ID = '" + ApplicationId + "') ORDER BY GP_REGION.REGION_MAIN",
                                             "REGION_NAME", "Region_Code", ref ErrorMessage, true);
```

and following is table structure

```
"REGION_CODE" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "REGION_NAME" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "REGION_MAIN" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
    "REGION_SHORT" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "REGION_HAS_DATA" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "REGION_CRM_CODE" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
    "REGION_CRM_ID" NUMBER(2,0), 
    "REGION_IS_SUB" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_GP_REGION" PRIMARY KEY ("REGION_CODE")
```

Comment: what does your GP_REGION object look like?

Comment: that is a table entity where want to get data and fill in to a dropdownlist

Comment: but surely you have created your EF model objects? I am asking to see them

Answer (score 0):

It is rework. if you want to change ADO.NET to EF. better option is change dataset or datareader to IEnumerable then you can apply Linq.Put a wrapper around ADO.Net  for LINQ.

If you have SQL query and want to convert in equivalent LINQ query then.  [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) is a SQL to LINQ converter tool. It helps you to learn LINQ and convert your existing SQL statements.

Comment: atleast if that query can replace with LINQ , i will do the rest,Can you replace that sql query with linq

Comment: See,  you can not replace sql query into LINQ, until you make a Linq to sql or EF object. LINQ is C# wrapper for sql server query.

Comment: i converted table in to EF generated classes see the code i have doneGPentities db1 = new GPentities(); i am using this in my controller.so only pending task is to fetch data from table by using LINQ

Comment: See my second paragraph of answer.